# Error while executiong my pyspark code in Databricks notebook

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While executing my PySpark code, throwing below error. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks
Error:

```
An error occurred while calling o508.sql.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromString(CharStreams.java:222)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromString(CharStreams.java:212)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parse(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parsePlan(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$2(SparkSession.scala:818)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:815)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor760.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _While executing my PySpark code_ Perhaps you could [edit] your question and post your PySpark code and indicate (if possible) which part of it is causing the error? Then maybe someone will be able to discover what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException is thrown when you try to access or invoke a methos on a object that is 'null'

You can try give checks to the input string that you are passing to the fromString method is not null. Also, look for any variables that might have unexpected null values.